# Isomorphism Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

I'm currently going through a proof and I've come across something I don't really understand:

---

> Next, an endomorphism of a left $A$-module $M$, over a ring $A$ is an $A$- homomorphism $M\rightarrow M$; these form a ring End$_A(M)$, where addition is given by the rule $(\phi + \psi)(x):=\phi (x)+\psi (x)$ and multiplication by composition of maps. If $A$ is a $k$-algebra, then so is End$_A(M)$, for multiplication by an element of $k$ defines an element in the centre of End$_A(M)$. In the case when $A$ is a division algebra, $M$ is a left vector space over $A$,  so the usual argument from linear algebra shows that choosing a basis of $M$ induces an isomorphism End$_A(M)\cong M_n(A)$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$ over $A$.

---

I don't understand the "usual argument from linear algebra" part. I don't know what argument it might be referring to. I understood well up until that point. I'm assuming that $M_n(A)$ are the $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients from $A$. To be honest I'm not sure what the difference between a left vector space and a left module is. I thought that vector spaces were only defined over fields, where the concepts of left and right coincide.

If anyone could clarify, I'd be extremely grateful, as proof that follows this is essential to my dissertation. Thanks for any replies!

Comment: A left vector space has a division ring as its scalar ring. This is a big deal, since you can invert scalars! Linear algebra is much easier than working with modules because of this. "The usual argument from linear algebra" is that since elements of $\text{End}_A(M)$ are linear, it suffices to define them in terms of a basis of $M$, etc.

Comment: A left module $M$ over a ring $A$ is called a left vector space over $A$ when $A$ is a division ring.

Comment: @Mike Yes, but you need to be carefull - you can divide, but multiplication is not commutative, so $a = bx$ doesn't imply $a = xb$ and vice versa. You thus basically need to decide from which *side* you'll be multiplying your vectors with scalars, which is why you call it "left vectorspace".

Comment: Fix an $A$-basis $v_1, ... , v_n$ for $M$.  If $\phi \in End_A(M)$, you can let $\phi \mapsto A_{\phi}$, where $A_{\phi}$ is a matrix whose coefficients $a_{ij}$ are given by the formula $\phi(v_j) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ij}v_i$.  It isn't difficult to show that this an isomorphism of abelian groups (that is, it preserves addition).

Comment: @Shankman I think that would suffice as an answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. @shankman I've almost shown that this is an isomorphism. Let $f:\text{End}_A(M) \rightarrow M_n(A)$, $f(\phi)=A_\phi$. Then I've shown that $f$ is an injective homomorphism, but to show surjectivity I have to show that every matrix $B\in M_n(A)$ is mapped to. So the function $\psi_B : M \rightarrow M$ defined by the formula you gave me, $\psi_B(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}v_i$ maps to $B$ under $f$. So I have to prove that $\psi_B$ is an A-endomorphism, else it is not in the domain of $f$. I can show that it's a homomorphism, but struggling to show the surjectivity.

Comment: An $A$-endomorphism of $M$ is just an $A$-module homomorphism from $M$ to $M$.  It doesn't have to be surjective.  So once you showed that $\psi_B: M \rightarrow M$ is a homomorphism of left $A$-modules with $f(\psi_B) = B$, you're done.

Comment: Oh ok duh, that was stupid of me. Thanks a lot.